# Hosting in germany or switzerland - significant difference?

Tags: internet, geolocation

We are an ecommerce store with 95% of our customers located in switzerland. Right now we are hosting in germany (Servers in Berlin) and thinking about hosting in switzerland. The cost is almost the same - so it´s just a matter of speed.

Is there a huge difference between locations only 900km far away? I mean there is probably only one junction in between. But I wonder if it makes more sense hosting locally.

Comment: *"so it´s just a matter of speed."* 

Mostly of latency, actually. - The additional roundtrip time for traffic routed over Germany compared to remaining in Switzerland would be  approximately 12 milliseconds,  which for most website user experiences is probably negligible

Comment: So you say it does not really matter where the server is located, as long it is in Europe / Swiss area?

Comment: The most significant differences will be legal issues.

Comment: I seem to recall that for the user experience  you need a 100 millisecond or more latency difference to get a noticeable effect. So if the geographical distance is the only concern, moving your servers 900 km closer to your users won't  have an immediately significant/obvious beneficial effect for them.

Comment: Thank you for the answers - I will go into the legal stuff with my colleagues

Comment: As @GeraldSchneider points out: there may also be other business drivers, legal, V.A.T. and other tax benefits , do you need physical access to the datacenter  etc.